# Advanced filter criteria for blank cell with formula

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using Advanced Filtering in Excel to quickly filter through set criteria. I have determined the 'criteria range' which is "=" meaning value should be blank but when I have formula in the cell, it does not filter blank value. How can I get around this problem in excel advanced filtering?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Are your values **numbers** or **text**?

Comment: It's actuslly blank, normally with no values the filtering works but the moment I use formula in those blank cells, it does not